# Flutter CheckboxListTile add trailing or leading icon

Tags: flutter

CheckboxListTile has a property that adjusts the position of the Checkbox. For example  `controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading`. But how do I get access to `"trailing"` place, like in regular ListTile? I would like an icon to be placed in this trailing place.

[image]

Comment: By default (in android) the checkbox icon appears in trailing as a regular ListTile trailing icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign widget you want to set in trailing to `secondary` in `CheckboxListTile`.